# oracle instant client 12.1 SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

I try to install oracle instant client 12.1 in .rpm with sqlplus in .zip on a cloud linux box, but I got error: Message file sp1.msb not found.

instant client and sqlplus download URL: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

After digging on the internet, I still cannot figure it out.

```
my ~/.bash_profile：
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
export NLS_LANG=american_america.utf8

source ~/.bash_profile

echo $PATH
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/bin
echo $ORACLE_HOME
/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64
```

sqlplus is unzipped in /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/bin, otherwise command cannot be found.

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution, hope helpful. After unzip the Oracle instant client archive I have to create some directories, move files and create tnsnames.ora manually. This is the layout after my setup:

```
$ pwd
/home/oracle/instantclient_11_2
$ find . -type f|egrep -v "sdk|htm|README"
./lib/ojdbc6.jar
./lib/ojdbc5.jar
./lib/xstreams.jar
./lib/libsqora.so.11.1
./lib/libnnz11.so
./lib/libociei.so
./lib/libsqlplus.so
./lib/libocijdbc11.so
./lib/libsqlplusic.so
./lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
./lib/libocci.so.11.1
./bin/adrci
./bin/sqlplus
./bin/odbc_update_ini.sh
./bin/genezi
./bin/uidrvci
./sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql
./network/admin/tnsnames.ora
```

Sample tnsnames.ora:

```
$ cat /home/oracle/instantclient_11_2/network/admin/tnsnames.ora 
ACNTUAT =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.54.32.10)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = acntuat)
    )
  )
```

Environment variables in ~/.bashrc (for all OS users)

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle/instantclient_11_2
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export SQLPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
export NLS_DATE_FORMAT="YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"
```

At this time, the command 'sqlplus user/passwd@acntuat' should work.